# O365 Outlook API throwing exception "An unexpected 'StartObject' node was found for property named 'Start' when reading from the JSON reader."

Tags: c#, outlook, office365api

I'm using the Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices nuget package, and using a service account to authenticate. I'm then calling the following...

```
var eventResult = await calendarClient.Users.GetById(resourceId).Calendar.Events.ExecuteAsync();
```

..and I can see data coming back from the API via fiddler, but I get the following error...

```
"An unexpected 'StartObject' node was found for property named 'Start' when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected."
```

Looks like the issue is that the API expects a datetime value for "Start" but is getting a datetimeoffset object.

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the v2 of that package, which supports the v2 endpoint that it sounds like you're using :). https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0/

Also, I just want to point out that these packages aren't being actively developed anymore, so new features in the API won't be available in the package (like the [rooms API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/06/30/announcing-new-rest-apis-in-beta-for-rooms-time-zones-and-languages/), etc.).

Comment: Ah, didn't realiise there was a V2 package. Works perfectly now, thanks!